# Converting sas7bvew to sas7bdat

Tags: sas

Is there a way to convert .sas7bvew to .sas7bdat format? I'm unable to locate the .sas7bdat file and only have the .sas7bvew formatted file.

Not sure if this is how to locate the .sas7bdat file used for the initial conversion to a .sas7bvew but I tried the following

`data view=[file name]; describe; run;`

This gave me a location; however, the file does not seem to be here

Comment: Does the view work or not?  Can you print the first 3 observations from it? `proc print data=libref.viewname(obs=3); run;'`

Comment: Guessing your view doesn't work because you can't find the sas7bdat file then? Unfortunately not aware of a workaround for that. You'll need to search for the sas7bdat file on your OS/system or ask a colleague.

Comment: Correct, the view doesn't work because the sas7bdat was removed from the location

Answer (score 2):

To copy the data that a view generates just run a simple data step.

So if you have a file named `myview.sas7bvew` in a directory named `/mydirectory/` then you could run code like this to create a dataset name mycopy in the work directory.

```
libname mylib '/mydirectory/';
data mycopy;
  set mylib.myview;
run;
```

If you want to write the dataset back to the same place then give it a different name. You cannot have a view and dataset with the same name.

```
data mylib.myview_copy;
  set mylib.myview;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks, Tom. Issue is the original sas7bdat file the view reads from doesn't exist in the specified location anymore so the data steps come up with an error; see below

ERROR: File {location of original sas7bdat data] does not exist.
ERROR: Failure loading view [sas7bvew data]. Error detected during View Load request.

Comment: I gather that the only work around is to locate the original sas7bdat dataset?

Comment: We cannot help you search your computer for files.

Comment: If your view points to a non-existent file, you're basically out of luck. The view effectively points to a file and runs some code. If that file isn't where the view is expecting it to be, the view will fail. You'll have to place the file back where it should be to run the view.